# How to add help to CommandCollection click's command?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I'm trying to add help to the command line application using click library. As mentioned in [official documentation](http://click.pocoo.org/5/documentation/#command-short-help),

> For commands, a short help snippet is generated. By default, it’s the
>   first sentence of the help message of the command, unless it’s too
>   long. This can also be overridden

With simple @click.command everything works as expected:

```
import click

@click.command()
def cli():
    """This is sample description of script."""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Running this would display description for the script from the method's doscstring:

```
Usage: example.py [OPTIONS]

  This is sample description of script.

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.
```

But I need to use CommandCollection, as I'm creating a script consisting from multiple commands. Here is an example from [official help](http://click.pocoo.org/5/commands/#merging-multi-commands):

```
import click


@click.group()
def cli1():
    pass


@cli1.command()
def cmd1():
    """Command on cli1"""


@click.group()
def cli2():
    pass


@cli2.command()
def cmd2():
    """Command on cli2"""


cli = click.CommandCollection(sources=[cli1, cli2])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

And I don't know how to add description to whole command collection. What I've tried so far:

- provide help with additional *short_help* parameter
- set *__doc__* argument for cli parameter, after creating CommandCollection
- add docstring to *cli1* method, decorated with @click.group

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Just use *help* parameter:

```
cli = click.CommandCollection(sources=[cli1, cli2], help="This would be your description, dude!")
```